# Using PHP SourceGuardian increases filesize?

Tags: php, performance, encoder

i'm trying out a PHP Encoder called source guardian..

https://www.sourceguardian.com/

as with other encoders it promises faster page loads..

but i noticed that my encoded php files are marginally bigger than my original files.. how can that be faster?

Just wanted to check with any SG users here on stack if they're experiencing any bloated files and if it affects performance?

Comment: Bigger files does not necessarily mean slower.

Comment: I would imagine the obfuscation is what is making your file sizes bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just bigger filesize doesn't mean slower page loads. They could be doing it like HHVM and compiling it [J]ust [I]n [T]ime in binary. That does make the page loads faster. Incredible faster. Tested it on a production environment. At least 3 times faster than with PHP5-FPM.

Comment: ahh.. did you mean you tested Source Guardian on a prod environment?

Comment: No, I was talking about HHVM, because they're using a JIT compiler and compiling the php code in binary to produce massive faster page loads (2-25x) and less memory usage. But Source Guardian could be doing it the same. I don't really know Source Guardian and their source code, so I don't really know how they're really doing it.

Comment: ahh thanks for the clarification... but for me, SG encoded files doesnt look binary.. here's what part of it looks like : sg_load('ABB6C1703A2482A1AAQAAAAWAAAABGgAAACABAAAAAAAAAD/86QMI2AyxCHKYhUjAK8UzJN3EYcO/mtMvDZ3u1uhbCQO8GoZWLQOyQSn4M8Y6e2uK/fd84A/ZOtnP1/Pln9DH5zYQYAYJxSREghGvRchV8bZrjSvQTTD19fgRtCsSDrW05YpFq6xWJc2AAA

Comment: Yes, because it's encoded. The compiled file could be binary.